# NextJS and Firebase Hosting - Access dynamic route directly, redirects to index.js on production

Tags: reactjs, routes, next.js, firebase-hosting

I haven't found any documentation on this behavior but here it goes...

Basically I have established an index.js page and a dynamic [address].js page.

Problem I'm facing here is that whenever I visit the [address].js page with something like "/helloworld" as an endpoint, I get redirected to index.js when I fully expected the contents of [address].js to show.

This is only happening after deployment to firebase hosting and not happening in localhost environment.

As a workaround, I added this code snippet to the useEffect method on index.js to route back to [address].js everytime I get redirected to index.js. This feels very inefficient.

```
const path = router.asPath;

if (
  path &&
  (path !== "/[address]")
) {
  Router.push(`${path}`);
}
```

Comment: Can you post your full `index.js` code and also the `[address].js` code?

Answer (score 0):

Here to provide some clarity and understanding around the problem.

It turns out that my issue with dynamic routing has nothing to do with NextJS and more to do with static hosting of sites on the firebase platform.

Here's an article that helps to cover this concern about dynamic routes on firebase hosting: https://medium.com/hackernoon/firebase-to-the-rescue-dynamic-routing-via-hosting-functions-integration-aef888ddf311